# Not able to access file via SMB but able to access from NTFS

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, smb2

I have a strange problem.

I have a file uploaded by some colleague via mapped drive. She is able to read the file after uploading. She has write/read/execute/list NTFS permission, and I see she is the owner of files.

Then some other colleague tell me she can't read these files via mapped drive, they have the same NTFS permission and sharing permission.

Then I test by myself, directly on the server:
1. I can't read either from mapped drive, and I logged as admin user
2. I can read it, via NTFS physical drive.
3. All sharing is inherited from the sharing root.

From ACL checking everything is correct. Other folders/files from the same sharing root is ok.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What are the permissions of the _share_ itself (via fsmgmt.msc)?

Comment: Change/Read for Domain Users at the root.